# OS X Startup Disk full, cannot login

Tags: macos

File storage is full, got spinning wait cursor when trying to access files to delete them, rebooted and now I can not get past the user login.  I enter password but cannot login.

Comment: Have you gone into Recovery HD and verify/repair disk?

Comment: Could you explain the goal? The system cannot work when the drive is full. Do you want instructions to wipe it and restore from a backup? Or to boot and delete some apps and files you know you can download again? When is the last full backup and do you trust it?

Comment: Also. Welcome to Ask Different. In addition to the help screens you read before posting, see [ask] on how to meet our question quality standards.

Comment: Yes and all verify checks are ok

Comment: Boot and delete some files would be best.  I believe movies are my best option to delete.

Comment: Please let me know how to delete files from terminal mode since I can not get past the user login due to startup disk being full.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

Deleting files in this circumstance is relatively easy but you will need to be at least a little conversant with Unix/Linux command line operations.

Boot your Mac holding down <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, this will pop you into single-user mode. A black screen with white text scrolling by. Eventually you will get a prompt with some instructions on what to do directly above it. I don't remember exactly but the commands mount the filesystem so you can access it. Then enter this:

```
cd /Users/[USERNAME]/Movies
```

Where [USERNAME] is your short username that appears on your home folder. Once in the movies folder you can proceed to delete movies. remember a couple of things.

1. The command line is Case Sensitive. So MySpecialMovie.mov is a different file than myspecialmovie.mov. At least at the command line level. (The Mac preserves case but in Finder operations is not case sensitive)
2. The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is your friend. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> when typing a file name and it will autocomplete.

Start by listing the files in your ~/Movies folder like this:

```
ls
```

Or you could get a longer listing (which I prefer).

```
ls -al
```

That will give you a list of all the deletable files.

The second method will give you file size.

To remove one of the files:

```
rm MySpecialMovie.mov
```

Now it is a matter of going through the ~/Movies folder using `ls` and `rm` to view and remove un-needed files.

Note that pressing the *Up Arrow* will scroll back in command history allowing you to easily review what you have done and/or repeat previous commands. *Down Arrow* scrolls forward in command history.

One you are done you can issue the reboot (restart?) command and allow your Mac to boot normally.

Comment: Hmm, I have found that my command like is case-insensitive though…

Comment: But after Command+S, we need to login. What if we cannot login? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443817/i-accidentally-removed-etc-now-i-cannot-login-or-put-it-back