# I accidentally removed /etc. Now I cannot login or put it back

Tags: macos, mac, restore, sudo

I deleted the `/etc/` folder and it is now in Trash.
I cannot put it back as it needs permission, and when `sudo` asks for the password, I enter and it doesn't work (as everything seems was in that `etc`).

Now I cannot even login into my machine.

How can I put that `etc` folder back to the `/private/HERE` folder?

**Update:**
I have access to Terminal through Recovery Mode. The `Users/` only shows the `Shared` folder and not my user.

Comment: As a user how did you remove /etc? or do you have admin access on your user account?

Comment: By `sudo` it was possible, unfortunately!!!

Comment: So you already had SIP disabled?

Comment: @nohillside No, it is enabled. `csrutil status` -> System Integrity Protection status: enabled.

Comment: Ah, would have assumed that at least /etc itself is under SIP. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

- Boot into Recovery Mode
- Open the Terminal from Recovery menu
- Type `chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD" zsh`
- Type `mv /Users/[yourusername]/.Trash/etc /private`
- Restart

Comment: You can skip the `chroot` step by running `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/; mv Users/[yourusername]/.Trash/etc private/` directly.